# How ngFor loop works with nested components and their contexts?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor, ng-template

### Goal

Allow list items to be deleted, moved up and down after rendering with `ngFor` loop.

### Problem

Moving and deleting is done correctly on the list. But after moving an item up, `ngFor` renders strange results: the item being moved is still on its place and also copied to the desired position while the item at that position is not rendered (but still everything okay in list itself).

Also, after delete operation angular throws:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroyed' of null
>       at ViewContainerRef_.move ....

Moving items down works as expected (all list operations are done with `array.splice` method).

### About list templates

The loop with a wrapper around list item component:

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of list; let itemIndex = index; trackBy: trackByItemId">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="itemTemplate; context: { $implicit: { item: item, index: itemIndex, service: listOperationsService} }"></ng-container>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-template #itemTemplate
               let-data>
    <app-list-item [item]="data.item"
                       [service]="data.service"
                       [index]="data.index">
    </app-list-item>
  </ng-template>
```

List item component's template:

```
<div class="item">
    <app-item-content [model]="item"></app-item-content>
    <button (click)="service.moveUp(index)">Move up</button>
    <button (click)="service.moveDown(index)">Move down</button>
    <button (click)="service.delete(index)">Delete</button>
<div>
```

### What I've tried

1. When I provide `trackBy` function which returns a simple item's `index`, `ngFor` renders the list properly. But when `trackBy` returns `item.id` or I provide no `trackBy` function at all, the described problem arises.
2. As of my knowledge in Angular, I assumed that everything inside `ng-template` is isolated from other instances in other `ng-template`s and destroyed as long as there is no respective item in the list. So I wrapped `app-list-item` with `ng-template`.

### Question

Why `ngFor` duplicates an item when it is moved up and does not delete the item when it is already removed from the list and throws the error?

I guess the problem somewhere in component nesting and contexts. Appreciate your ideas.

---

**Update**: Everything worked fine when the list was rendered without nested components, i. e. only with `ng-container`s, `ng-template`s and plain html. I decided to use nested components because of refactoring reasons.